# Lambda expression that returns a delegate

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, lambda, expression

Hi I am trying to achive something like this;

```
Method<TObjectType>(m=>m.GetData); //m is the instance of TObjectType
```

if I can succeed on that, then I can visit this expression and get the GetData Method and use it for creating a dynamic sql query. I could do this by giving method name as a string however I don't want to break the strongly type world of my developer friends.

I know I have to give the exact definition of the delegate but this still doesn't helped me;

```
void Method<TObjectType>(Expression<Func<TObjectType, Delegate>> ex){/**/}
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Do you know anything about `GetData()`? Do you know that it will always have zero parameters, or something like that?

Comment: If you do not know the signature of the GetData method you will be leaving the strongly typed world.

Comment: This might help you as well
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840438/lambda-returning-another-lambda

Comment: @svick signature of the method should be generic because this could be any method.

Comment: @Erno I thought so I am afraid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's barely such a thing as "a delegate". For most purposes (and especially: for resolving a `MethodInfo`), it must be a strongly-typed delegate. This is because `GetData` isn't a *method*, it is a *method group*. You really need to specify the method precisely, or have a known delegate-type (which ultimately does the same thing).

You have two practical options; work to `object`, or add a generic. For example:

```
void Method<TObjectType>(Expression<Func<TObjectType,object>> ex) {...}
```

would work, as would:

```
void Method<TObjectType, TValue>(Expression<Func<TObjectType,TValue>> ex) {...}
```

The caller would use:

```
Method<Foo>(x => x.GetData());
```

---

If you **really** want to use a delegate, the type must be predictable, for example:

```
void Method<TObjectType>(Expression<Func<TObjectType,Func<int>>> ex)
```

allowing:

```
Method<Foo>(x => x.GetData);
```

Alternatively, if you know (for example) that the method is always parameterless, but you don't know the return type; maybe something like:

```
void Method<TObjectType, TValue>(Expression<Func<TObjectType,Func<TValue>>> ex)
```

which allows:

```
Method<Foo, int>(x => x.GetData);
```

Comment: In this scenario I suppose you are assuming that the GetData method is parameterless so that you can define it using the Func<T>. Which means, I have to make lots of Method overrides, am I correct?

Comment: @lazycoder I would advise against it, because you'll end up making a method with an insane number of generic type arguments, that is rather inconvenient to call. I would actually advise the simpler `object`/`TValue` approach, with the caller specifying `x.GetData()`. For more complex overloads, they can always specify `x.GetData(123, "abc", DateTime.Now)` - the expression tree will tell you what overload they used, and (if you want them) the parameter values.

Comment: @lazycode Worst case, you then need two overloads; one `Func<TObjectType,object>`, one `Action<TObjectType>` (for `void` methods)

Comment: thanks, I suppose I have two ways; one way is to force the developer to define at least one parameterless override and second is to as Erno said "leaving the strongly typed world." :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
object InvokeMethod(Delegate method, params object[] args){
    return method.DynamicInvoke(args);
}

int Add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

void Test(){
    Console.WriteLine(InvokeMethod(new Func<int, int, int>(Add), 5, 4));
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I don't want to invoke this method I just want developers to define something with strongly typed